# Order reverse to a float value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

As you can see from the value "val" I generate values ​​from 0 to 255, how can I reverse the order of this float value?

```
-(UIColor *)colorForIndexToWhite:(NSInteger)index {    
    NSInteger itemCount = _gradientArrayToWhite.count - 1;
    float val = ((float)index / (float)itemCount) * 0.9;
    UIColor *colorFromHEXCode = [UIColor colorWithHexString:_hexCode];
    NSString *myCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", (colorFromHEXCode.red*255)-(val*255)];
    NSLog(@"Red Value: %.f - val: %.f - Result: %@", colorFromHEXCode.red*255, val*255, myCount);
    return MP_RGB((colorFromHEXCode.red*255)-(val*255), (colorFromHEXCode.green*255)-(val*255), (colorFromHEXCode.blue*255)-(val*255));
}

This is the Output:

    2013-10-02 16:14:02.473 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 0 - Result: 70
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.475 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 26 - Result: 44
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.475 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 51 - Result: 19
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.476 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 76 - Result: -6
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.477 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 102 - Result: -32
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.478 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 128 - Result: -58
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.478 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 153 - Result: -83
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.479 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 178 - Result: -108
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.480 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 204 - Result: -134
    2013-10-02 16:14:02.480 Goolor[993:a0b] Red Value: 70 - val: 230 - Result: -160
```

Comment: Reverse? You mean when you get a 0 you want to convert to 255 and when you get a 255 you want to convert to 0?

Comment: 255-x will go from 255 down to 0 as x goes from 0 to 255.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068294/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-this-float-value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
(color*255)-(val*255)
```

do

```
color * val * 255
```

Btw. I think you just copy paste it from somewhere. Right now it generate values from 255 to around 50, not to 0... you have 0.9f on float val + index will be never equal itemCount.